# How to start with CiviCRM and creating an extension to add Contact Tab in PCP

Tags: civicontribute, civicrm-home

I'm new to CiviCRM. I tried to create an extension for CiviCRM to add a tab in PCP and access CiviCRM from the videos on youtube and the document. But I failed to start. 
I'm trying to create a Contact Tab in CiviCRM which displays a list of the personal campaign pages that a contact has created.

The tab should show the personal campaign page title (with a link to the page), status, contribution page or event that it is funding for, no of contributions, amount raised, target amount and a link to the edit page form.

Which approach should I follow to get acquainted with CiviCRM and thus able to create an extension. I'm using CiviCRM on Drupal.

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what you want to achieve with your extension?

Comment: I've elaborated the question!

Answer (score 2):

You can find instruction on how to create an extension in the CiviCRM documentation here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension

I would recommend you first think about:

- what hooks are you going to use (check https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference)
- what API calls are you going to need
- do you need to create new pages, forms, reports or API's?

Comment: I've elaborated the questions. For that stuffs what should I start with?

Comment: Have you read the introduction on how to create an extension? That is where you should start.